# Undefined Margin/Padding at bottom of body

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I've tried using chrome's developer tools to isolate the problem but can find the culprit there is a margin or padding at the bottom of this page I'm developing. It looks like a margin on the body or the footer but I just can't seem to find it. Looking for a fresh pair of eyes.

http://idwebhosta.net/~engravea/about-engraveables/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the copyright p margin in the footer.

```
p.copyright { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The margin-bottom on your copyright class seems to be the culprit.
If I set it to zero then the white space at the bottom goes away.